# How to indicate a return type that is nested (e.g. a list of ints)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

I have a python function with nested return types, how can I indicate the return types correctly? (For example pycharm might detect the return type as [Tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html)[[list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric), [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric)] where every type is linked individually)

e.g.

```
def random_list(num):
    """Returns a list of random numbers
    :param num:
        Number of random numbers to generate
    :type num:
        int
    :return:
        A list of random floats
    :rtype:
        ????
    """
    return [random() for x in range(num)]
```

Comment: `[float]`, obviously? Or even better, merely `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and use the same expression, e.g:

```
from typing import List

def random_list(num: int) -> List[float]:  # Py 3.5
    """Returns a list of random numbers
    :param num:
        Number of random numbers to generate
    :type num:
        int
    :return:
        A list of random floats
    :rtype:
        List[float]
    """
    return [random() for x in range(num)]
```